# Usage of libC in linux kernel and standalone programming

Tags: libc

We can use standard C library routines in standalone micro-controller programming but we cant in linux kernel. my question is, in both cases while they are running on the target hardware both of them dont have access to the libC this explains the "linux kernel" case but what happens when it comes to the standalone application on some micro controller(say MSP430).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Programs running on embedded controllers typically are linked with a (suitably small) version of the standard library. The kernel is not linked to the standard C library, thus it can't be used.

Comment: may i know the reason for not linking C library with kernel

Comment: @srikanthM, How would it work? Some of the utilities are standalone, but a large majority of libc relies on system calls. If you _are_ the OS, how can you use such a library?